# Where can I find a list of possible events for an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, element, onchange

I'd like to know the possible events that can come from an HTML span element. Is there some documentation somewhere for each HTML element that says what events it can trigger and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list below is the closest that I have found.. Not sure if it covers all of them!! Notice that there is no onChange event handler for the span tag. Instead, you will have to use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree.

```
+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Event          |onActivate                      onAfterUpdate                 |
| Handlers       |onBeforeActivate                onBeforeCopy                  |
|                |onBeforeCut                     onBeforeDeactivate            |
|                |onBeforeEditFocus               onBeforePaste                 |
|                |onBeforeUpdate                  onBlur                        |
|                |onClick                         onContextMenu                 |
|                |onControlSelect                 onCopy                        |
|                |onCut                           onDblClick                    |
|                |onDeactivate                    onDrag                        |
|                |onDragEnd                       onDragEnter                   |
|                |onDragLeave                     onDragOver                    |
|                |onDragStart                     onDrop                        |
|                |onErrorUpdate                   onFilterChange                |
|                |onFocus                         onFocusIn                     |
|                |onFocusOut                      onHelp                        |
|                |onKeyDown                       onKeyPress                    |
|                |onKeyUp                         onLoseCapture                 |
|                |onMouseDown                     onMouseEnter                  |
|                |onMouseLeave                    onMouseMove                   |
|                |onMouseOut                      onMouseOver                   |
|                |onMouseUp                       onMouseWheel                  |
|                |onMove                          onMoveEnd                     |
|                |onMoveStart                     onPaste                       |
|                |onPropertyChange                onReadyStateChange            |
|                |onResize                        onResizeEnd                   |
|                |onResizeStart                   onSelectStart                 |
|                |onTimeError                                                   |
+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the list but my question is which ones are specific to span. For example I just made a contenteditable span and tried copy pasting but got no oncopy or onpaste events. And your linked page lists Media Events and Window Events which don't apply to span. Here's all the events I get when I type a letter in my contenteditable span (it's between form tags): https://www.screencast.com/t/75jCCg1hrmWb 
Why didn't it trigger onchange? If I change it to an input element I do get a change event. What is textInput?  That's not even in the w3schools list of events.

Comment: Check out my edited answer, does that list satisfy your question?!
List is all there, there is no onChange event for the span tag, you must use MutationObserver Instead.

Comment: Where did you get that list in your answer from?

Comment: It's not official documentation, but I found it here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSSReference/HTML-Tag-Reference/spanEventHandlers.htm

Comment: Ok that's just what I was looking for, thanks! It's a shame the official documentation isn't as thorough